# where is the patch code?

Tags: linux, patch, uvc

I'm following [these instructions](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/usb/gadget-testing.txt#L660) to test a UVC function. [It says](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/usb/gadget-testing.txt#L727) to apply [these patches](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-usb/msg99220.html), but all I see is text and how many changes were made. I don't see any actual patches. Am I missing something? Is there a link missing somewhere?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The patches are in the follow-ups to the main email at http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-usb/msg99220.html

See the follow-ups section below the main email. The emails with the subjects `[PATCH 1/4] ...` to `[PATCH 4/4] ...` contain the actual patches.